# TVJS player in Apple TV misfiring the event mediaItemDidChange in tvOS14 beta version

Tags: apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

We are using TVJS player in our application on Apple TV.
During the testing of our application on tvOS14 beta with Xcode 12.0 beta 4, we observed that none of the videos were playing as expected as the event **mediaItemDidChange()** is firing unexpectedly.This event is triggered by the player itself.

In the previous version this is triggered when the user has played till end or forwarded to end. We tested the same in old version which is working fine.

In case of new beta version it is triggered on the loading itself and media is changed by the event listening function on the initial loading of media thereby causing infinite loop kind of effect.

Do we have any video player issues in tvOS 14 beta version? Did anyone come across the same issue while testing the application in beta version?

Comment: We have other issue - player.next() is firing "mediaItemDidChange" with event.reason === 0 (unknown) instead of 4 or 5 like described in docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvmljs/player/1627385-mediaitemdidchange